# Order ID, Purchase Time on Itunes connect

Tags: ios, google-play, app-store-connect, itunes-sdk

I want to make a data base with IOS and Android app.

They have similarities like: `packageName`, `price`, `currency`, `title`, `description`, `productID`, `type`, `trialPeriod` and more...

But they are 2 major field that I cannot find on Itunes connect or in the [in-app Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase): `orderID` and `purchaseTime`.

I know the user can get the `ORDER ID` and `DATE` within Itunes: [image: Order Id for users]
Where can we find this `ORDER ID`/`DATE` for developer side?